# How do I retrieve text that comes that comes after the <strong> tag using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use `Beautiful Soup` to pull all text values after all `strong` elements. I've been able to pull the following `bs4.element.ResultSet` from this [source](https://www.njmls.com/listings/index.cfm?action=dsp.info&mlsnum=20003254&dayssince=15&countysearch=false):

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
<td style="width:38%; vertical-align:top;">
<strong>MLS#:</strong> 20003254<br/>
<strong>Town:</strong> West New York<br/>
<strong>Address:</strong> 6050  Boulevard East , Unit 7 J<br/>
<br/>
<strong>Current Price:</strong>    $590,000<br/>
<strong>Previous Price:</strong>    $599,000<br/> <strong>Original Price:</strong>     $649,900
                                                                        </td>
<td style="width:31%; vertical-align:top;">
<strong>Style:</strong>Condo<br/> <strong>Bedrooms:</strong> 2<br/> <strong>Full Baths:</strong> 2<br/> <strong>Half Baths:</strong> 0<br/> <strong>Basement:</strong> Bin/Storage<br/>
<strong>Garage:</strong> Pkg Space In
                                                        </td>
<td style="width:31%; vertical-align:top;">
<strong>List Date:</strong> 01/24/2020<br/>
<strong>Category:</strong> Condo/Coop/Townhouse<br/>
<br/>
<strong>Taxes:</strong>      $9,408 <br/><strong>Monthly Maintenance:</strong><br/>$     1,140.00
                                                        </td>
```

I want to pull all the following values into a list:

```
[20003254,West New York, 6050 Boulevard East Unit 7 J, $590,000, $599,000] and so on for all values above.
```

I have been using the following to pull the titles of the data values I want into a list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests import get

headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})

sapo = "http://www.njmls.com/listings/index.cfm?action=dsp.info&mlsnum=20003254&dayssince=15&countysearch=false"
response = get(sapo, headers=headers)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
containers = html_soup.find_all('table',{'style': 'width:100%;'})

for cont in containers:
        a = cont.find_all("strong")
        a = [i.text.strip() for i in a]
print(a)
```

This returns:

```
['MLS#:', 'Town:', 'Address:', 'Current Price:', 'Previous Price:', 'Original Price:', 'Style:', 'Bedrooms:', 'Full Baths:', 'Half Baths:', 'Basement:', 'Garage:', 'List Date:', 'Category:', 'Taxes:', 'Monthly Maintenance:']
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 a = [i.text.strip() for i in a]
```

to

```
 a = [i.next_sibling for i in a]
```

which gives

```
>>> [' 20003254', ' West New York', ' 6050  Boulevard East , Unit 7 J', '    $590,000', '    $599,000', '     $649,900 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \t', 'Condo', ' 2', ' 2', ' 0', ' Bin/Storage', ' Pkg Space In\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', ' 01/24/2020', ' Condo/Coop/Townhouse', '      $9,408 ', <br/>]
```

Comment: Not sure, but think you may mean `i.next_sibling` without `text`...?